# Cast struct to array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I'm currently learning C and I have trouble understanding the following code:

```
struct dns_header
{
    unsigned char ra : 1;
    unsigned char z : 1;
    unsigned char ad : 1;
    unsigned char cd : 1;
    unsigned char rcode : 4;
    unsigned short q_count : 16;

};

int main(void)
{
    struct dns_header *ptr;
    unsigned char buffer[256];

    ptr = (struct dns_header *) &buffer;

    ptr->ra = 0;
    ptr->z = 0;
    ptr->ad = 0;
    ptr->cd = 0;
    ptr->rcode = 0;
    ptr->q_count = htons(1);

}
```

The line I don't understand is `ptr = (struct dns_header *) &buffer;`

Can anyone explain this in detail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `buffer` is simply a contiguous array of raw bytes. They have no semantic from the `buffer` point of view: you cannot do something like `buffer->ra = 1`.

However, from a `struct dns_header *` point of view those bytes would become meaningful. What you are doing with `ptr = (struct dns_header *) &buffer;` is mapping your pointer to your data.

`ptr` will now points on the beginning of your array of data. It means that when you write a value (`ptr->ra = 0`), you are actually modifying byte 0 from `buffer`.

You are casting the view of a `struct dns_header` pointer of your `buffer` array.

Comment: Is it better to use an array instead of malloc?

Comment: @user4793972, re: "better", that depends on the details. Here, we know exactly how much space we need at compile time -- this wouldn't be possible at all if you needed to allocate a dynamically determined amount of space, and it also wouldn't work if we needed any code to be able to refer to the buffer after the function exited (as it is, any pointers into that buffer will become invalid... or, rather, the behavior of accessing them will become undefined... as soon as the function exits).

Answer (score 2):

The buffer is just serving as an area of memory -- that it's an array of characters is unimportant to this code; it could be an array of any other type, *as long as it were the correct size*.

The struct defines how you're using that memory -- as a bitfield, it presents that with extreme specificity.

That said, presumably you're sending this structure out over the network -- the code that does the network IO probably expects to be passed a buffer that's in the form of a character array, because that's intrinsically the sanest option -- network IO being done in terms of sending *bytes*.

Comment: Are there any good reason for using an array instead of the malloc function?

Comment: @user4793972, well, the array here is allocated on the stack and is automatically deallocated when your function exits, whereas if you use malloc you get memory from the heap, and need to deallocate it yourself or else it leaks.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to allocate space for the struct so you could

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct dns_header));
```

which will return a pointer to the allocated memory,

```
ptr = (struct dns_header *) &buffer;
```

is almost the same, except that in this case it's allocated in the stack, and it's not necessary to take the address of the array, it can be

```
ptr = (struct dns_header *) &buffer[0];
```

or just

```
ptr = (struct dns_header *) buffer;
```

there is no problem in that though, because the addresses will be the same.

Comment: @user4793972 if you are using malloc, then you must not take the address of the pointer `&buffer` but the pointer itself (because it points to memory allocated by `malloc`): `ptr = (struct dns_header *)buffer`.

Comment: I got it to work with malloc now. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

> The line I don't understand is ptr = (struct dns_header *) &buffer;

You take the address of the array and pretend like it is a pointer to a `dns_header`. It is basically raw memory access, which is unsafe, but OK if you know what you are doing. Doing so will grant you access to write a `dns_header` in the beginning of the array.

Ideally, it should be an array of `dns_header`s not a byte array.  You have to be cautious about the fact that `dns_header` contains bit fields, the implementation of which is not enforced by the standard, it is entirely up to the compiler vendors. Although bit field implementations are fairly "sane", there is no guarantee, so the size of a byte array might actually be mismatched with your intent.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers posted:

This code is illegal since ANSI C. `ptr->q_count = htons(1);` violates the strict aliasing rule.

It is only permitted to use an `unsigned short` lvalue (i.e. the expression `ptr->q_count`) to access memory that either has no declared type (e.g. `malloc`'d space), or has declared type of `short` or `unsigned short` or compatible.

To use this code as-is, you should pass `-fno-strict-aliasing` to gcc or clang. Other compilers may or may not have a similar flag.

An improved version of the same code (which also has some forwards-compatibility to the structure size changing) is:

```
struct dns_header d = { 0 };
d.q_count = htons(1);

unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *)&d;
```

This is legal because the strict aliasing rule permits `unsigned char` to alias anything.

Note that `buffer` is currently unused in this code. If your code is actually a smaller snippet of larger code then `buffer` may have to be defined differently. In any case, it could be in a union with `d`.

Comment: Matt are you saying that `ptr->q_count = htons(1);` violates strict aliasing because `ptr` and `buffer` both point to the same memory location under different types and `q_count` is not type qualified as a `char` or because there is something else inherently wrong with the  `ptr->q_count = htons(1);` assignment itself?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin `ptr->q_count` has type `unsigned short`, but it is accessing memory of type `unsigned char`

Answer (score 0):

A struct directly references a *contiguous block* of memory and each field within a struct is located at a certain fixed offset from the start. Variables can then be accessed via a struct pointer or by the struct declared name which returns the same address.

Here we declare a *packed* struct which references a *contiguous block* of memory:

```c
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct my_struct
{
    unsigned char b0;
    unsigned char b1;
    unsigned char b2;
    unsigned char b3;
    unsigned char b4;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Pointers can then be used to refer to the struct by its address. See this example:

```c
int main(void)
{
    struct my_struct *ptr;
    unsigned char buffer[5];

    ptr = (struct my_struct *) buffer;

    ptr->b0 = 'h';
    ptr->b1 = 'e';
    ptr->b2 = 'l';
    ptr->b3 = 'l';
    ptr->b4 = 'o';

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        putchar(buffer[i]); // Print "hello"
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here we explicitly map `1:1` the struct contiguous block of memory to the contiguous block of memory pointed by `buffer` (using the address to the first element).

An array address and the name of the address are numerically identical but have different types. These two lines are thus equivalent:

```c
ptr = (struct my_struct *) buffer;
ptr = (struct my_struct *) &buffer;
```

This is usually not a problem if we use the address *as is* and cast it appropriately. Dereferencing an array address of type *pointer to array-of-type* yields the same pointer but with a different type *array-of-type*.

Although it might seem convenient to manipulate memory in this fashion, it is *strongly* discouraged as the resulting code becomes painfully difficult to understand. If you really have no choice, I suggest using an union to specify that the struct is to be used in a particular manner.